# What is the easy way to limit the download speed on apache host?

Tags: apache

I'm trying something and I need to download a file with low speed from my website.(like 10KBps). Is there any easy way to set that speed limiter on server or host for only a specific directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the module `mod_ratelimit` which is included in httpd package.
Here is an implementation on CentOS 7:

1. Enable the `mod_ratelimit` module:

   ```
   vi /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf
   ```

   uncomment line 72:

   ```
   LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
   ```
2. Create a config file for `mod_ratelimit`:

   ```
   vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/ratelimit.conf
   ```

   then put this content in:

   ```
   #limit bandwidth as 500KB/sec under the [apache_DocumentRoot_directory]/specific_directory
   <IfModule mod_ratelimit.c>
           <Location /specific_directory>
               SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
               SetEnv rate-limit 500
           </Location>
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. Restart your httpd service using:

   ```
   systemctl restart httpd.service
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Apache has a `mod_ratelimit` designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what tools or OS you are using, but `curl` has an option to limit the bandwidth it uses:

```
curl --limit-rate 200K
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that RHEL8.8 has the mod_ratelimit.so located here:

```
[user@server conf]# grep rate /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-optional.conf
LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
```

And the httpd daemon accepted the filter parameters within Directory section:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
    SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
    SetEnv rate-limit 100
</Directory>
```

I was able to test this, the download become slow after httpd restart.